# display an (x)html document structure in a new window

Tags: html, xml

For debugging purpose, I need to create an new xml document popup to display the (x)html source structure of my current document.

But the following code does not work:

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.open('text/xml');
w.document.write(window.document.documentElement.innerHTML);
w.document.close();
```

It seems that `document.open()` does not accept contentType anymore.
Is there any other solution ?

Comment: You want to see the SOURCE of the document in this new window?

Comment: Why can't you use an existing debugger with a DOM inspector such as Chrome Developer Tools, Opera Dragonfly, Firebug, etc, etc, etc?

Comment: Good suggestion David Dorward, but I cannot use these tools.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a textarea in your existing page and copy the innerHTML into the textarea.

Comment: I need to display the XML structure of the document.